# WHS on VMWare - how to install as a virtual image

Tags: virtualization, windows-home-server

I have tried to install an instance of WHS (Windows Home Server) on VMWare server v1.x and I get a message while installing the OS that it needs his own 80GB or greater HD.  What's the trick ... it seems that allowing or setting a vhd > 80GB does not help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this is what you'll need to do:

1. The virtual disk does need to be 80GB or greater.
2. You need to set the SCSI controller to BusLogic
3. During the first phase of the WHS install (initial GUI phase), if you're prompted that a compatible hard drive can not be found, you'll need to load the BusLogic driver from a virtual floppy (vmscsi-1.2.0.4.flp)

http://download3.vmware.com/software/vmscsi-1.2.0.4.flp

4. During the second phase of WHS install, during the "blue screen" phase, you need to press F6 to load the driver from floppy again.
5. During the "name your server" phase of set up, you need to disconnect the virtual NIC, otherwise you'll get errors stating that a duplicate name already exists on the network.

I just installed WHS on ESXi 3.5 U4 yesterday and these are the steps I had to take to get it installed.